# Getting views path from the controller#action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, haml

I need to compile (via HAML) and get the contents of the view file. Right now I'm doing this inside an action of the controller:

```
path     = File.join(views_path, 'recommend/email_texts/video_uploaded.html.haml'))
contents = File.open(path) { |f| f.read }
message  = Haml::Engine.new(file).render(self)

# file is being rendered in a context of self because it includes some action
# specific vars, as well as calls to params method of controller
```

Then I need to send the message to the SOAP endpoint and render a "Operation successful" page to the browser. *Just saying*

So the question is – is there a suitable approach I can replace the 3 lines above with? If there's not much to refactor here – is there any good practice to accomplish tasks of a kind I am working on?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this ought to be equivalent:

```
message = view_renderer.render self,
            :template => 'recommend/email_texts/video_uploaded'
```

Related docs:

- [`AbstractController::Rendering#view_renderer`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-view_renderer)
- [`ActionView::Renderer#render`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Renderer.html#method-i-render)
- [`ActionView::TemplateRenderer`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/master/ActionView/TemplateRenderer)